# resizing layer returns wrong shape

Tags: python, keras

At the beggining of my keras model, Im trying to do some resizing to my grayscale images. Here is the relevant code:

```
# Input tensor
height, width = X.shape[1:]
input = keras.Input(shape=(height,width), name='Input')

# Model
preprocessing = definePreprocessing(trial, input)
preprocessed = preprocessing(input)



def definePreprocessing(trial, X):

    preprocessing = keras.Sequential(name='Preprocessing')

    # Normalization
    preprocessing.add(keras.layers.Rescaling(name="Normalize", scale=1./255))

    # Resizing
    preprocessing.add(keras.layers.Resizing(
            50, 
            50,
            interpolation="bilinear",
            name="Downsample"))

    return preprocessing
```

When I inspect the layers, this is what I get:

```
 Normalize (Rescaling)       (None, 224, 224)          0         
                                                                 
 Downsample (Resizing)       (50, 50, 224)             0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
```

My question is: why does the Downsample layer output is (50, 50, 224) instead of (None, 50, 50)?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after much digging, I found this in the documentation:

"This layer resizes an image input to a target height and width. The input should be a 4D (batched) or 3D (unbatched) tensor in "channels_last" format."

(https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_preprocessing/resizing/)

So, it seems it is mandatory to specify the number of channels even if the image is grayscale. I was expecting a 3D batched image, and it must be 4D.

Comment: Can you please share the link to the document in your answer. That will be helpful for others to get some more context.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).